# What are my options to create a const or static string as the result of a function call in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to have a `const` or `static` which is a random number appended by a dot. In Java it produces what I want, but in Rust I get variety of errors

```
const SOME_STR:  &'static str = format!("{}.", rand::random::<u64> ()).as_str();

static SOME_STR:  &'static str = format!("{}.", rand::random::<u64> ()).as_str();
```

I get errors like

1. calls in statics are limited to struct and enum constructors
2. static contains unimplemented expression type
3. borrowed value does not live long enough

What are my options here and what is an easy way to fix this?

Comment: [How can you make a safe static singleton in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27221504/3650362) has an example of using the `lazy_static` crate for a similar use case. [Here's an application of the same strategy to your problem.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ec5d8b67727c2d8cc569dc563fdf2661&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to follow up on a basic question 
Why cant I do static ref PREFIX: &'static str = format!("{}.", rand::random::<u64>()).as_str(); in a single line. Why should I take an extra pointer?

Comment: `format!` returns a `String`, which would be dropped if you called `.as_str()` on it without saving it somewhere. With `lazy_static!` only the final value of the initializer expression is saved and leaked. You could instead write what `lazy_static!` does manually, and leak the `String` directly, but at best you're saving a couple bytes.

Comment: If you don't want to expose the `String` to your public API, you could split the `lazy_static!` into a public part and a private part in a non-public module. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=46e261333adacdcc130ab91a4899260d&version=stable&mode=debug)