# Rust atomic no warning when trying to mutate

Tags: rust, atomic

In rust, if I have the following code

```rust
const foo: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);
*foo.get_mut() = true;
println!("{}", foo.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
```

it prints false. There are no warnings (except to do with capitalization), and there is no errors, at compile time or runtime, but the value is not changed, which is not expected behavior. If the variable is declared using `let` or `static`, the compiler throws the following errors:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `foo` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
 --> src\bin\main.rs:6:6
  |
4 |     let foo: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);
  |         --- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut foo`
5 |     //const bar: AtomicBool = foo;
6 |     *foo.get_mut() = true;
  |      ^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

for `let`, and

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable static item `foo` as mutable
 --> src\bin\main.rs:6:6
  |
6 |     *foo.get_mut() = true;
  |      ^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

for `static`.

Throwing an error like this is what I would expect, as I am trying to get a mutable borrow of an immutable value, so I have two questions:

1. Why is no such error thrown for `const`, and
2. What is the correct way to use a global variable like this, as `const` does not seem to produce the inteded behavior

Related github issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40543

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50631189/11326662

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me. `const`s aren't variables and they don't act like variables. If you disagree, please [edit] the question to explain how it's different.

Comment: As for question 2., it seems you've already figured out that `static` is the way to create a "global" variable, so... why look any farther than what you've already seen works?