# Iron persistent state with struct reference

Tags: rust, iron

I'm struggling with getting a persistent reference working with Iron, not sure how to set an appropriate lifetime. I want to be able to re-use the controller on different routes.

**Example:**

```
use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::typemap::Key;
use persistent::Read;
use router::Router;

pub struct Controller;

pub struct Rest {
    controller: Controller,
}

impl Key for &Controller {
    type Value = Self;
}

impl Rest {
    pub fn run(&self) {
        let router = Router::new();
        let mut chain = Chain::new(router);
        chain.link(Read::<&Controller>::both(&self.controller));
        Iron::new(chain).http(format!("0.0.0.0:1234")).ok();
    }
}

fn main() {
    Rest {
        controller: Controller,
    }
    .run();
}
```

```
[dependencies]
iron = "0.6.*"
router = "0.6.*"
persistent = "0.4.0"
```

[Gist of example](https://gist.github.com/blechatellier/a4fabf9251250cfa208b817a2d6b5b73)

```
error[E0478]: lifetime bound not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl Key for &Controller {
   |      ^^^
   |
note: lifetime parameter instantiated with the lifetime '_ as defined on the impl at 12:14
  --> src/main.rs:12:14
   |
12 | impl Key for &Controller {
   |              ^
   = note: but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime

error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'_` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl Key for &Controller {
   |      ^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime '_ as defined on the impl at 12:14...
  --> src/main.rs:12:14
   |
12 | impl Key for &Controller {
   |              ^
   = note: ...so that the types are compatible:
           expected typemap::Key
              found typemap::Key
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `&Controller` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:12:6
   |
12 | impl Key for &Controller {
   |      ^^^
```

Comment: *I want to be able to re-use the controller on different routes* — and do you want the persistent data to be globally shared across all of these routes, or does each route have its own unique persistent data?

Comment: I want the persistent data to be globally shared across all of these routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states:

> but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime

This is because [`Key`](https://docs.rs/iron/0.6.0/iron/typemap/trait.Key.html) uses [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) as a supertrait, which requires `'static`:

```
pub trait Any: 'static {
    fn type_id(&self) -> TypeId;
}
```

The simplest solution is to implement `Key` for a value and then give the value to `Read::both`:

```
impl Key for Controller {
    type Value = Self;
}

impl Rest {
    pub fn run(self) {
        let router = Router::new();
        let mut chain = Chain::new(router);
        chain.link(Read::<Controller>::both(self.controller));
        Iron::new(chain).http(format!("0.0.0.0:1234")).ok();
    }
}
```

> I want the persistent data to be globally shared across all of these routes

In that case, I'd eschew using the persistent crate completely and just create a singleton:

- [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423)
- [How can you make a safe static singleton in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27221504/155423)

Comment: what does the more complicated solution would look like if I wanted to have a reference to the controller?

Comment: @BriceLechatellier sorry for the ambiguous wording — there is *no* way to implement `Key` for a reference, unless the reference is `'static` (a.k.a. a global), so there is no "complicated" solution. I mean that the provided solution is the simplest working solution, starting from your proposed structure. I've linked to alternate Q&A that show how to have such a global.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an explicit lifetime bound to your `impl` block. Otherwise the compiler has no clue on the reference validity of the controller reference.

This should work, though I have not tested it

```rust
pub struct Rest {
    controller: controller::Controller,
}

impl<'a> Key for &'a controller::Controller {
    type Value = Self;
}

impl Rest {
    pub fn run(&self) {
        let mut router = Router::new();
        let mut chain = Chain::new(router);
        chain.link(Read::<&controller::Controller>::both(&self.controller));
        Iron::new(chain).http(format!("0.0.0.0:1234"))
    }
}
```

On a side note, I don't think you need to specify the type on the `Read` call, the compiler should be able to determine it from the context.

Comment: Thanks, edited the main question with the suggestion, still throwing errors regarding the lifetime.