# Why does an unsafe implementation of Sync and Send cause the structure to become non 'static?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to create a structure that serves as a wrapper for a global `'static` constant singleton. To do so, I created a struct `Wrapper` containing a pointer to `T`.

```
fn main() {
    let s = Box::new(TestStruct {}) as Box<dyn TestTrait>;
    let l = Wrapper::new(s);
    tokio::spawn(async move { l.run().await });
}

struct Wrapper<T: Send + Sync + 'static> {
    ptr: *const T,
    // _phantom: std::marker::PhantomData<T>, // Use instead of ptr for tests
}
impl<T: Send + Sync + 'static> Wrapper<T> {
    pub fn new(item: T) -> Self {
        todo!();
    }
}
impl<T: Send + Sync + 'static> std::ops::Deref for Wrapper<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        todo!();
    }
}
unsafe impl<T: Send + Sync + 'static> Sync for Wrapper<T> {}
unsafe impl<T: Send + Sync + 'static> Send for Wrapper<T> {}

trait TestTrait: Send + Sync {
    fn run(&self) -> futures::future::BoxFuture<()>;
}
struct TestStruct {}
impl TestTrait for TestStruct {
    fn run(&self) -> futures::future::BoxFuture<()> {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

```
error[E0477]: the type `std::boxed::Box<dyn TestTrait>` does not fulfill the required lifetime
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     tokio::spawn(async move { l.run().await });
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

The problem is strange because if I remove `unsafe impls` and replace `ptr` with `_phantom`, the program compiles. It looks like adding an `unsafe impl` with a `'static` lifetime breaks some internal checks.

To sum up:

- no pointer in struct, no `unsafe impl`s - no error
- pointer in struct, no `unsafe impl`s - error, because `ptr` is not `Sync` + `Send`, that's fine
- no pointer in struct, `unsafe impl`s - error, not `'static` (???)
- pointer in struct, `unsafe impl`s - error, not `'static` (???)

I've read [How do I create a global, mutable singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27791532/155423) and [How can you make a safe static singleton in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27221504/155423). I'm not interested in how to make a global singleton, I'm curious why my example won't compile, whether it is compiler bug or where exactly I am wrong in my code.

Comment: Notice that, apparently, you are about to save `*const Box<...>` in your wrapper, which, as soon as `Wrapper::new` exits, will be a dangling pointer.