# "temporary value dropped while borrowed" - How to work with Path list references?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to send a list (Vec or array) as function parameter to an (async) function. Each Path is used to spawn a thread which does some action on that file.

The problem here is, I'm not able to find correct way to make the references live long enough. I added 'static lifetime in the function parameter as this works in the threads. But now I cannot get a reference to meet this requirement when calling this function.

Here is a small example of my problem. The original code is much more complex.

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn main() {
    // Get paths from somewhere
    let paths = vec![
        PathBuf::from("/path/to/file.txt"),
        PathBuf::from("/path/to/file2.txt"),
    ];

    // Do multithreaded work with these paths
    do_something(&paths.iter().map(|path| path.as_path()).collect::<Vec<_>>());

    // Here some things regarding those files would happen.
}

fn do_something(paths: &'static [&Path]) {
    // Here paths is used again and required to use 'static lifetime
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `paths` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:11:19
   |
5  |     let paths = vec![
   |         ----- binding `paths` declared here
...
11 |     do_something(&paths.iter().map(|path| path.as_path()).collect::<Vec<_>>());
   |                   ^^^^^                   -------------- returning this value requires that `paths` is borrowed for `'static`
   |                   |
   |                   borrowed value does not live long enough
12 | }
   | - `paths` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:11:19
   |
11 |     do_something(&paths.iter().map(|path| path.as_path()).collect::<Vec<_>>());
   |     --------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |     |             |
   |     |             creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
   |     argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

Comment: If you really want to stick with references you'd probably have to [make a static singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27221504/how-can-you-make-a-safe-static-singleton-in-rust/76397461#76397461) and can then generate references to it. But why can't you just pass around `Arc<[Box<Path>]>` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

In your code the `&'static Path` refers to the temporal object created with the `collect`, not the `vec!` from above, doing something like this should work for you, the `impl Iterator<Item = &'a Path>` is to be generic over the different types that can come like `Map<Iter<Cycle<..>>>`

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn main() {
    // Get paths from somewhere
    let paths = vec![
        PathBuf::from("/path/to/file.txt"),
        PathBuf::from("/path/to/file2.txt"),
    ];

    // Do multithreaded work with these paths
    do_something(paths.iter().map(|path| path.as_path()));

    // Here some things regarding those files would happen.
}

fn do_something<'a>(paths: impl Iterator<Item = &'a Path>) {
    // Here paths is used again and required to use 'static lifetime
}
```

Comment: In this specific example this works. But in my project this doesn't work. Is there any way to get this working without changing the function parameter type?

Comment: imposible without cloning the data, because you at most have a &[PathBuf] but to get a &[Path] you need to transform the PathBuf

Comment: Impossible is a harsh word for something that can be done, there is `Box::leak` after all, though that's not really the correct solution here.

Comment: "impossible without cloning the data"

Comment: Uhm creating a reference is not "cloning the data" neither is creating a new `Vec` from those references.

Comment: It's impossible that having a `Vec<PathBuf>` you can get a `&[Path]`, since there is no place in memory where contiguous Paths are placed, so you would need to allocate new memory for a `Vec<Path>` with the map of `Vec<PathBuf>` and then take the reference

I suggested using a Iterator since that way a `Map<Iter<Item = &PathBuf>>` can represent that without doing any extra allocation

Comment: Yes, but creating an allocation is something completely different than "cloning the data".

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I should have been more clear with my first answer. Either way in this case the allocation can only be a clone

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using `std` for spawning threads, maybe scoped threads could help you with those path lifetimes.

From [std::thread::scope](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html):

> Unlike non-scoped threads, scoped threads can borrow non-`'static` data, as the scope guarantees all threads will be joined at the end of the scope.

With your example, this runs:

```rust
fn do_something(paths: &[&Path]) {
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for path in paths {
            s.spawn(move || {
                dbg!(path);
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `thread_local!()` macro:

```
thread_local! {
    static PATHS: RefCell<Vec<PathBuf>> = RefCell::new(vec![
        PathBuf::from("/path/to/file.txt"),
        PathBuf::from("/path/to/file2.txt"),
    ]);
}
```

Because `thread_local!()` wraps the `Vec<PathBuf>` into a `RefCell`, `paths` in `let paths = p.borrow();` is a borrowed reference `std::cell::Ref<'_, Vec<PathBuf>>` to that `RefCell`.
So neither is here cloning needed nor changing the type for the function argument of `do_something()`:
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=4c60354fd1362c41602aa06014aa8133)